# MYSQL, PHP: Insert records from one database to another

Tags: php, mysql

I have a necessity to insert some record from one table1 in database1 to another table2 in database2.
So far I have this..

```
    $records_r = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn_r, "SELECT * FROM `export` WHERE ID < 100"));        

    $columns_r = implode(",",array_keys($records_r));
    $values_r = implode(",",array_values($records_r));          

    $import = mysqli_query($conn_i,"INSERT INTO NOTimport ($columns_r) values ($values_r)");
    if (!$import) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($conn_i));
    exit();}
```

It gives me the error:

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

This is how the syntax looks:

```
INSERT INTO `NOTimport` ('xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx,xx') values ('11,'11,E,2079,1931,xx,xx,x')
```

I am 99% sure that single quotes are causing the error, but why are there?

Comment: No, $conn_r if for one database, $conn_i is for another database.

Comment: this is failing `INTO import ($columns_r) values ($values_r)` but your error message doesn't tell us much.

Comment: so if you do var_dump($import) what kind of SQL syntax it shows you?

Comment: Try putting back-ticks around `import`. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

Comment: can you checked the query string by echo. just echo "INSERT INTO import ($columns_r) values ($values_r)" then copy the query genrated and run in your mysql

Comment: stealth edit `INSERT INTO NOTimport` and without marking it as an additional edit and everyone stands at being downvoted for it. thanks

Comment: We don't know what your values are. It is best to use parameterized queries then you won't run into quote issues. Try echoing your query.

Comment: So I created a new thread and finally get what I wanted.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134168/while-loop-for-mysqli-results/31134378?noredirect=1#comment50279879_31134378

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Using PHP you can use MySql Query Which Will Perform Insert Operation As:-

```
$columns_r='`name`,`class`';

mysqli_query($conn_i,"INSERT INTO `import` ({$columns_r}) select {$columns_r} from `export`");
```

Answer (score 4):

As per your original post https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31116693/1 and completely overwriting your original post without marking it as an edit:

You're using the MySQL `import` reserved word
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

It needs to be wrapped in ticks

```
INSERT INTO `import` ($columns_r) values ($values_r)
```

or rename that table to something other than a reserved word.

Plus, `$values_r` may require to be quoted and depending on what's being passed through `$columns_r`, you may need to use ticks around that.

I.e.:

```
INSERT INTO `import` (`$columns_r`) values ('".$values_r."')
```

Even then, that is open to SQL injection.

So, as per your edit with these values `values ('11,'11,E,2079,1931,xx,xx,x')`, just quote the values since you have some strings in there. MySQL will differentiate between those values.

Escape your values:

```
$values_r = implode(",",array_values($records_r));
$values_r = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn_r, $values_r);
```

or `$conn_i` I'm getting confused as to which variable is which here. Be consistent if you're using the same db.

Edit:

As stated in comments by chris85, use prepared statements and be done with it.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
- http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

Comment: Nota: OP made a stealth edit without marking it as an edit to their original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31116693/1

Comment: How can I quote the values?

Comment: @ZetaAl `values ('".$values_r."')` as stated in my answer and you could use escaping values for it too. Plus, I've made an edit where I marked it as an edit. Reload it.

Comment: @ZetaAl I also made an additional edit, reload everything and see the part about **Escape your values:** and using `values ('".$values_r."')` but prepared statements would fix that in a jiffy.

Answer (score 1):

`import` is a reserved word in MYSQL. So, you need to use backticks (``) around it in your query.

So rewrite as follows:

```
 $import = mysqli_query($conn_i,"INSERT INTO `import` ($columns_r) values ($values_r)");
```

Comment: I was typing mine up at the same time so I didn't want to abondon it lol will upvote though

Comment: Lol. It's ok. What matters is that the OP is helped and their problem solved.

Comment: no, import is there just to in this "stackoverflow" example...the real name of the table is not import..lol